# When will Kovri be launched (approximately)?

Tags: kovri

Just checked [the github](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/) and I was wondering when Kovri will come out from its Alpha version... I'm not actively following the developing process because I don't have enough experience / skill, but how much time you think the devs team will need? Is EOY / 2019 too optimistic?

Comment: 2 weeks.  (sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: Is this a meme? :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha version should be presented at DefCon, so 9 - 12 August.

Edit:
alpha release on August the 1st
Workshop at defcon on August the 11th.

Source: [github issue](https://github.com/monero-project/meta/issues/252)

Comment: Don't see it on the speaker sched.  Is it a village, skytalk, demolab, etc?

Comment: Not sure, but from kovri meeting log 2018/06/07: "<anonimal> 4. Alpha release discussion
<anonimal> The date is by defcon."

Comment: Ah, 'by' not  'at'.  (so 2 weeks :) )

Comment: By defcon may be just the 9 in the morning ;) anyway it's soon now.

Comment: Edited with more accurate Info.

Comment: FYI: [v0.1.0-alpha release](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/releases/tag/v0.1.0-alpha) was 8 days ago.